# How to define new instantaneous variable row by row - RAILS3 BEGINNER

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I was hoping somebody may be able to point me in the right direction...

I have a database called Info and use a find command to select the rows in this database which match a certain criteria

```
@matching = Info.find( :all, :conditions => ["product_name = ?", distinctproduct], :order => 'Price ASC')
```

I then pull out the cheapest of these items

```
@cheapest = @matching.first
```

Finally, I would like to create an instantaneous array which contains a list of @cheapest for a number of different search criteria. i.e. row 1 in @allcheapest is @cheapest for criteria 1, row 2 in @allcheapest is @cheapest for criteria 2, ...

Any help would be great, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Info.where(:product_name => distinct_product.to_s).order('Price ASC').first
```

to select the cheapest price for the product_name.  Without more insight into how your database is structured, it is difficult to suggest how to obtain the latter, but you may try

```
Info.where(:product_name => distinct_product.to_s).order('Price ASC').group(:product_name)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.  I guess i was hoping that the 2nd paert of the question was fairly generic, in particular, is it possible to set one instance variable (e.g. @cheapest which has say 10 columns) as a particular row number / an additional row in another instance variable (e.g. @allcheapest)?  Is the "puts" function a possibility? I was getting errors if this array was empty before i tried to use the puts function...

Comment: puts is simply used to print output to stdout.  Again, you need to provide more concrete details (with sample data) if you want assistance with part 2.